# Rendering a node sequence as M x N table

Tags: xslt

@Oded: Sorry to have been poor in my exposition... My input document has a fragment like this:

```
<recordset name="resId" >
<record n="0">example 1</record>
<record n="1">example 2</record>
<record n="2">example 1</record>
....
<record n="N">example 1</record>
</recordset>
```

containing an arbitrarily long  node sequence. The attribute "n" reports the order of the node in the sequence. I need to arrange as output that sequence in a M (rows) x N (columns) table and I have some trouble doing that. I cannot call a template

```
<xsl:template match="recordset">
   <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="record"/>
   </table>
</xsl:template>
```

with something like:

```
<xsl:template match="record">
<xsl:if test="@n mod 3 = 0">
    <tr>
</xsl:if>
........
<td><xsl:value-of select"something"></td>
```

because code is invalid (and I should repeat it at the end of the template in some way)
and I must put some (maybe too much) trust in the presence of the numbered attribute. Someone has a hint? Thanks!

Comment: You need to post some XML sample, with an XSL sample and the desired output. It is not very clear from your question what the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must ensure that nesting is never broken. Things you want nested in the output must be nested in the XSLT.

```
<xsl:variable name="perRow" select="3" />

<xsl:template match="recordset">
  <table>
    <xsl:apply-templates 
      mode   = "tr"
      select = "record[position() mod $perRow = 1]"
    />
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record" mode="tr">
  <tr>
    <xsl:variable name="td" select="
      . | following-sibling::record[position() &lt; $perRow]
    " />
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="td" select="$td" />
    <!-- fill up the last row -->
    <xsl:if test="count($td) &lt; $perRow">
      <xsl:call-template name="filler">
        <xsl:with-param name="rest" select="$perRow - count($td)" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record" mode="td">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="filler">
  <xsl:param name="rest" select="0" />
  <xsl:if test="$rest">
    <td />
    <xsl:call-template name="filler">
      <xsl:with-param name="rest" select="$rest - 1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: great solution. I was wondering if it'll still work for a variable with different accumulated elements, for example: <xsl:variable name="packageElements" select="Transfer | Coach | Flight | Train" /> instead of <recordset> element in this example. I'm trying to do it, but stuck. Will really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using msxsl processor. I'm stuck with trying to get the list of nodes in the $td variable. It selects the current node (specified as "."), but I can't figure out how to specify all the following nodes after current one from the $packageElements variable correctly.

Comment: @DashaLuna: This is nothing that can (or should) be answer in these comments. I think it's best to make a separate question, set a link here if you like, and show your XML and the XSLT you have so far.

Comment: Sorry about that, you're right. I have created a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997284/xslt1-0-rendering-sequence-of-different-elements-stored-in-a-variable-as-m-x-n-ta
Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Using xslt 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="rows">3</xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="recordset">
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="record" group-by="count(preceding-sibling::*) mod $rows ">
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0, using a general n-per-row template.

With the row element name as a parameter, the n-per-row template is not tied to you input or output format.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="recordset">
    <table>
      <xsl:call-template name="n-per-row">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="record" />
        <xsl:with-param name="row-size" select="2"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="row-element" select="'tr'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="n-per-row">
    <xsl:param name="select" />
    <xsl:param name="row-size" />
    <xsl:param name="row-element" />
    <xsl:param name="start">
      <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="count" select="count($select)" />
    <xsl:variable name="last-tmp" select="number($start) + number($row-size)" />
    <xsl:variable name="last">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$last-tmp &gt; $count">
          <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$last-tmp"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:element name="{$row-element}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$select[position() &lt;= $last]"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:if test="count($select) &gt; $last">
      <xsl:call-template name="n-per-row">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="$select[position() &gt; $last]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="row-size" select="$row-size"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="row-element" select="$row-element"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$start"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Lachlan: This solution does much more recursion than really necessary.