# xsl 1.0 group nodes by position

Tags: xml, xslt

these is my xml

```
 <elemetns> 
 <item>...</item>
 <item>...</item> 
 <item>...</item>
 <item>...</item> 
 ... 
 <item>...</item>
 <elemetns>
```

the out put shoud create a html table with 4 colums

```
<xsl:template match="Item" mode="single">
   from current position  4 items  and build the first row with item data
</xsl:template>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Several, several duplicates found with http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+xslt+list+in+table

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[XSLT\]: Rendering a node sequence as M x N table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355952/xslt-rendering-a-node-sequence-as-m-x-n-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach should help:

```
<xsl:template match="elements">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() mod 4 = 1]" mode="row"/>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="row">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::item[position() &lt; 4]" mode="cell"/>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="cell">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it with xslt 1.0 is to use keys:

Given this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<elements>
    <item>r1c1</item>
    <item>r1c2</item>
    <item>r1c3</item>
    <item>r1c4</item>
    <item>r2c1</item>
    <item>r2c2</item>
    <item>r2c3</item>
    <item>r2c4</item>
    <item>r3c1</item>
    <item>r3c2</item>
    <item>r3c3</item>
</elements>
```

the following stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>

    <xsl:key name="items-by-row" match="elements/item"
             use="floor(count(preceding-sibling::item) div 4) + 1"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//item[position() mod 4 = 1]" mode="row"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="row">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('items-by-row', position())" mode="cell"/>
            <xsl:variable name="span" select="4 - count(key('items-by-row', position()))"/>
            <xsl:if test="$span &gt; 0">
                <xsl:call-template name="handle-colspan">
                    <xsl:with-param name="span" select="$span"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="handle-colspan">
        <xsl:param name="span"/>
        <!--suppress CheckTagEmptyBody -->
        <td>
            <xsl:if test="$span &gt; 1">
                <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$span + 1"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="cell">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the following result:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>r1c1</td>
        <td>r1c2</td>
        <td>r1c3</td>
        <td>r1c4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r2c1</td>
        <td>r2c2</td>
        <td>r2c3</td>
        <td>r2c4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r3c1</td>
        <td>r3c2</td>
        <td>r3c3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please note that with the `handle-colspan` template I'm inserting additional `td` elements in order to produce correct tables.

Comment: With XSLT 1.0 the use of variables is not allowed in key expressions so Saxon 6.5.5 for instance complains "The expressions in xsl:key may not contain references to variables" for your sample stylesheet.

Comment: @Martin, fixed. Thought that processor should validate stylesheet against spec when `version` attribute is set to `1.0`.

Comment: Which XSLT processor did you use that does not raise an error?

Comment: Thought that it should be `Xalan` shipped with the JDK 1.6. But ATM I'm in doubt. To be precise - the one default in the Intellij Idea IDE.